# 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eclccPath')' in HPCC Systems VS Code extension

Tags: hpcc, hpcc-ecl

How to resolve this error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eclccPath')' in HPCC Systems VS Code extension.

I have installed ecl client tools. While installing I tried with both options 'add path to all users' once &  the default one 'do not add'. in both cases getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

Can you share which versions of the ECL Extension and Client tools your using?

Also the quick / normal setup:

1. Have a project folder which contains a sub folder (ECL Module) which in turn contains ECL files (ECL Attributes)
2. In VSCode open the "project folder"
3. Open an ECL file from the file
4. Create Launch Configuration
5. Select the target by:

   - Clicking the "Launch Configuration" in the status bar
   - Optionally clicking on the "Target Cluster" in the status bar

At which point you should be able to submit ECL to the server as specified in the launch configuration.

For example see:  https://github.com/GordonSmith/ECL-Playground

Comment: Hi Schmoo, I am using ECL extension version v2.22.2 and client tools version 8.10.10-1. I do have a project folder, ECL file and launch.json configuration file in the folder. When I submit the job it is giving error  "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eclccPath')' ".  Additionally the HPCC bundles and client tools are not loading in the activity bar.

Comment: To clarify, ECL Module = ECL Folder, and ECL Attributes = ECL Definitions

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have installed the Client Tools, make sure that you have the Client Tools active so that the eclcc compiler can be found. In the Client Tools list, there is an option to activate. And make sure that you are installing the OSX (Mac) Client Tools version.

Comment: Thanks Bob, How to activate client Tools? Where can I find the Client Tools list ?

Comment: Hi Jyothi, Click on the HPCC Systems icon in the Activity bar and the list of Bundles and Client Tools will appear. From there you can look at the Client Tools installed and activate the version you need.

Comment: The HPCC bundles and client tools are not loading. I tried disabling all extensions and then enabling all extensions. Also uninstalled VS code and ecl client tools and then reinstalled them.

Comment: Please see Schmoo's comments above.

Comment: Thank you Bob Foreman & Schmoo for your inputs. I was able to fix this issue by  Installing the x86 version of client tool 8.10.10.1(x86). So installation of a proper version of client tools based on your machine is the fix, thanks again.